# Why do all soldering irons have long barrels?

Tags: soldering

Why do all soldering irons have long barrels? Even temperature controlled ones? I can understand that it helps regulate the temperature of a tip if the heating element emits a constant power of heat. But I need to solder a 0.4mm pin pitch device and I'm guessing the stubbier the barrel the less shaky the tip will be when I hold it. If I were to make my own soldering iron, is there any reason not to have the tip close to the handle?

Comment: OTOH, a long barrel can make it easier to solder in tight spaces where your hand might not fit.

Comment: You also want to be somewhat away from the heat with your fingers.

Answer (score 2):

A typical soldering iron has the heating coil inside of the barrel, which influences the barrel length. There are professional soldering irons<sup>1</sup>, which use RF for heating they often have a shorter barrel.

<sup>1</sup> <sub>Metcal, for example.  Brace for price tag.</sub>
<sup>2</sup> <sub>[Review of a soldering station with teardown.](http://toolboom.com/en/Articles-and-Video/Lukey-868-Hot-Air-Soldering-Station-Review.html)  disassembled soldering iron shown around the middle of the page.</sub>